# Get added objects and removed objects from array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var A = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Apple"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Orange"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Mango"
}];

var B = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Apple"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Mango"
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: "Berry"
}];
```

I want to get added objects; `[{ id: 4, name: "Berry" }` 
remove objects; `[{ id: 2, name: "Orange" }]`

Please tell me the simplest way to do that. I tried with array difference and it's ok but the code is too complicated. Thanks.

Comment: Please, try it yourself and provide a [mcve] if it doesn't work.

Comment: Some basic research into how to determine array differences should get you at least a start point. This isn't a code writing service and you are expected to show your own attempts to solve your issues. So post the code you say seems complicated. This would also be a good time to read through [ask]

Comment: I am sorry if that's offensive. It's not my intention. I mean like if there is basic utility like underscore.js or other ready made functions to do that.

Comment: Do the added and removed objects always have exactly `id` and `name` properties?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do object comparison, the easiest way I can think of right now is 'stringify' it.

```js
var A = [{ id: 1, name: "Apple" }, { id: 2, name: "Orange" }, { id: 3, name: "Mango"}];
var B = [{ id: 1, name: "Apple" }, { id: 3, name: "Mango" }, { id: 4, name: "Berry" }];


var strA = A.map(function(item){return JSON.stringify(item);})
var strB = B.map(function(item){return JSON.stringify(item);})

var addedObjs = strB
                  .filter((item) => strA.indexOf(item) < 0)
                  .map((item) => JSON.parse(item));

var removedObjs = strA
                  .filter((item) => strB.indexOf(item) < 0)
                  .map((item) => JSON.parse(item));


console.log(addedObjs);
console.log(removedObjs);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm looking for. I used union, intersection and difference to get that. I am a noob. :D

Comment: This will fail if the order of the properties happens to be different between A and B.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, you're right. So a better solution would be recursively compare values of properties instead of 'stringify' it.